# How to install CentOS 7 64bit VBox guest in Windows Azure

Tags: windows, azure, virtualbox, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Windows Azure VM. The VM's CPU and OS is of 64 bit. I want to install a CentOS 7 64bit guest OS in VBox within the Windows Azure. But when I downloaded CentOS 7 64bit and try to install the same in the VBox, I get an error "VT-x is not available". When I searched for that in net I found that VT-x needs to be enabled in the BIOS. But since that is a Windows Azure VM, I don't have access to the bios and could not enable it.

[image]

So, is it possible in any way to enable VT-x for the Windows Azure VM, so that I can install the CentOS 7 64 bit?

**EDIT:** I found even installing CentOS 32-bit shows the same error. It is only about the V3 series and Hyper-V support as per @WayneYang-MSFT 's answer, and not related to 64-bit or 32 bit CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

---

Nested virtualization is supported in the **Dv3** and **Ev3** series of Azure virtual machines. It  supports enabling Hyper-V Features.

So, you can use Vitural Box on v3 series VM. I test in my lab which uses D2s v3 VM.

I used the virtual Box and installed a 64-bit ubuntu on it:

[image]

Also, I suggest you use Hyper-V for Nested virtualization on Azure VM. This feature will be supported by Microsoft. **Using third party virtualzation software is not supported by Microsoft.**

For more details, refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization).

Hope this helps!

Comment: One naive question. Given an Windows Azure VM, how can I identify if it is one of Dv3 and Ev3 series of Azure virtual machines? Any idea?

Comment: Hi, @Loganathan . `Go to Azure portal > Select your VM > Overview > Size`   the VM size of your VM is here. You can check if it is v3 series.

Comment: HI, @Loganathan  I test in my lab, Virtual Box can run on Auzre v3 series VM and I succeed install a Ubuntu in Vitural Box. You can also have a try.

Comment: Hi, I already installed VBox. But as in the question I don't have option to choose 64 bit CentOS linux and if try to proceed with Redhat 32-BIT, I get the VT-x error, which I can't fix in bios. My goal is to install CentOS 64-bit guest in the VM.

Comment: An update from my side is that I can't try with Hyper-V since I could not enable it. Trying to enable it give some compatibility error. So I only need to go with any possibility with VBox. So for now found no solution.

Comment: @Loganathan  Have you used a v3 series VM size VM?

Comment: The problem I have is I don't have access to the Azure portal to know what is the VM series. Based on your updated answer I can arrive that unlike your test which allows to install 64bit Ubuntu, I get the VT-x error means it could not be a V3 series VM. May be I should check with the admin. Thanks!

Comment: Edited: Another update is that even installing CentOS 32-bit shows the same error. So as you mentioned it is only about the V3 series and Hyper-V support, not related to 64-bit or 32 bit OS.